Can Boon Boon Boon give Legendaries, Duos, Infusions, or other Boons that have dependencies?
The description for Echo's "Boon Boon Boon" gift says "Gain a random Boon from the previous night".
How "random" is it? Can Boon Boon Boon give Legendaries, Duos, Infusions, or other Boons that have dependencies like Burnt Offering that usually takes a boon to acquire?
